# ¿Cómo puedo aplicar un estilo a un dato que pinto por pantalla pero esta dentro de un array en React?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, typescript

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo un componente que me visualiza por pantalla los elementos de un array en filas. Lo que quiero hacer es dar estilo a un elemento de ese array, para que se visualice de otro color por pantalla. El problema es que no conozco el nombre del elemento que lo contiene, ya sea un div o cualquier otro, por eso no puedo dar estilos propiamente a ese elemento, ya que el componente lo hace internamente.

Un ejemplo muy resumido:

```
var filas = ["Pepe", "Juan", "Manolo"]

<MyComponente filas={filas} />

filas[2].style.backgroundColor = "green"
```

Algo así.

Comment: Pon el código del componente de cada item para poderte ayudar

Answer (score 1):

Todo código que puedas aportar, ayudará a comprender tu problema.

No obstante, te intento ayudar:

Tu componente MyComponente debería de recorrer el array filas que le pasas como propiedad en su render:

## ES5

```
render = function() {
  return (
    <div>
      {
         this.props.filas.map(function(f, indice) {
           var newStyle = {background: 'blue'};

           if (indice % 2) {
             style.background = 'green';
           }
           return <div style={newStyle}>{f}</div>
         })
      }
    <div>
  )
}
```

## ES6

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {
         this.props.filas.map((f, indice) => {
           let newStyle = {background: 'blue'};

           if (indice % 2) {
             style.background = 'green';
           }
           return <div style={newStyle}>{f}</div>
         })
      }
    <div>
  )
}
```

Saludos